# Where is the right place to add an extension?

Tags: ios, swift

I found here an extension to shuffle arrays. Where is the best place to add this extension?

First I added it (never used an extension before) in the ViewController where I needed the functionality.

Later I needed it in another ViewController and pasted it again in, but got an error that it was already declared. But when I tried to use the `shuffle()` I didn't get any errors but my array didn't get shuffled at all.

So I wonder where the problem is.
Do I miss anything when using `shuffle()` in another ViewController? Any prefix or something?

Thanks!

Comment: How about in it's own file?

Comment: Hi, did you down vote my question? Why?

Comment: It describes code but doesn't show code. For this reason I down and close voted it.

Comment: ok, but my question not about the actual code, as I got it working. I am just asking about the best position for the extension. I don't think it makes sense to paste in here any code, as my question is not code - related.

Comment: `but my array didn't get shuffled at all.`

Comment: I was thinking this is about the way how I included the extension. Once I have this solved, I can test again and take care about the shuffling.

Comment: [*If you define an extension to add new functionality to an existing type, the new functionality will be available on all existing instances of that type, even if they were created before the extension was defined.*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)